# After Nextjs Build, I want to rename the chunk file

Tags: caching, next.js, webview, chunks

After Nextjs Build, I want to rename the chunk file and use new data instead of cached data, but manifest.json refers to the existing chunk file.
How can I resolve this issue?

I changed generateBuildId in next.config.js option, but it doesn't work properly, and it loads an existing chunk file even though I turned off cache.

Comment: Why do you want to rename the chunk? What exactly is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve? Please update your question with further details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solutions but this worked for me.

```
/* the trick is to build unique build ID on every build and add it to static files on build time.
 * This way the name and URL of static files will change on every build.
 */

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');

// Used to set folders as alias to directly use in nextjs
const nextConfiguration = ({
    webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
        const newConfig = config;

        if (!dev && newConfig.output.filename.startsWith('static')) {
            newConfig.output.filename = newConfig.output.filename.replace('[name]', `[name]-${ Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
            newConfig.output.chunkFilename = newConfig.output.chunkFilename.replace('[name]', `[name]-${ Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}`);
        }

        return newConfig;
    },
});

module.exports = nextConfiguration;
```

The code is adding a timestamp to the name of the created files every time that the project is compiled. With this when changes are deployed into live site the browser received "new" files and discard the ones cached.

Source: https://gist.github.com/amit08255/a4eb51d5302e71ba3ecb267bc2a6a5e5

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your next.config.js file. The 'generateBuildId' function has been configured to ensure cache-busting by creating a unique build ID with a date. Also, the webpack config hook is used to change the names of output files during the production build, adding a date to chunk filenames. Using timestamps helps to avoid caching issues, making sure you get the most recent versions of the files.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // Function for cache-busting
  generateBuildId: async () => {
    // Create a unique build ID with a combination of timestamp and a random string
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Get the current timestamp
    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8); // Generate a random string
    const buildId = `${timestamp}-${randomString}`; // Combine timestamp and random string
    
    return buildId;
  },

  // Webpack configuration
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    // Add a timestamp to filenames during production build for cache-busting
    if (!dev && config.output.filename.startsWith('static')) {
      const timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Get the current timestamp
      // Modify output filenames to include the timestamp
      config.output.filename = config.output.filename.replace('[name]', `[name]-${timestamp}`);
      config.output.chunkFilename = config.output.chunkFilename.replace('[name]', `[name]-${timestamp}`);
    }

    // Add other webpack configurations here

    return config;
  },

  // Other configurations...
};
```